# Comparison of all Android SDKs

Tags: android, sdk, versions

I had been given a assignment to prepare a presentation about this subject. Logically I went ahead and prepared such presentation about the all revision starting from SDK revision 3 to SDK revision 23.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXmzu.png]

Instructor refused this homework, saying I misunderstood the question. No further explanation. I have been searching for hours, I cannot seem to understand why is my answer is wrong. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: I would assume that when the instructor asks for a comparison, the instructor is expecting to see a comparison, describing the differences. Moreover, the highest Android SDK level at this point in time is 21, not 23.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [Help].

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you were instructed to prepare a presentation that COMPARES all of the android-sdks, you didn't actually do that.

All you did was give the dates for them...I don't see anything about what was added, what changed, major updates or removals...

Comment: In the next pages, all new features and fixes were mentioned.

Comment: @aliaktaş But did you COMPARE them, or just list updates? There's a big difference.